# how to access button/view of an activity from another activity

Tags: android

I have a button in an Activity and when on clicking this button, some operation will be performed in another activity. And I should call the buttonclick event in 2nd activity only.Simple saying, I have a TabActivity with button and upon clicking the button some operation should be performed  in the underlying tabs. ButtonClick event should be in the tab.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create one common function in a helper class and call it from both the places.

Comment: What is a helper class?? sorry I had never heard of it. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: instead of writing the function in the Activity, you need to write it in a separate class which can be accessed from both the activities.

Answer (score 1):

You could broadcast an Intent from your first activity to be received by your second activity. When your button is clicked, it's parent activity broadcasts a unique intent which your android manifest will route to your second activity for receiving.

There is a good example of that here:
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/

However, have a look at the [android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and consider using a [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) which is more appropriate if you are just broadcasting within your process.

Comment: I dont want to make it complicated.Anyway my problem got solved and thanks for the immediate reply